# ASP.Net Web API HttpClient doesn't send data to target Web API Uri

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, uri, httpclient, postman

I'm trying to post a data from a Web Api to another Web Api in different project solution with a controller like this

```
public class PublishWebController : ApiController
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task<Uri> CreateArticleAsync(Article article)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/articles", article);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }

    void Main()
    {
        Post().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    //POST api/<controller>
    [Mime]
    public async Task<Article> Post()
    {

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64395/api/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var fileuploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
        var multiFormDataStreamProvider = new MultiFileUploadProvider(fileuploadPath);
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(multiFormDataStreamProvider);
        string uploadingFileName = multiFormDataStreamProvider.FileData.Select(x => x.LocalFileName).FirstOrDefault();

        return new Article
        {
            Title = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Title"],
            ArticleContent = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ArticleContent"],
            ImagePath = "~/Images/" + Path.GetFileName(uploadingFileName),
        };

    }
}
```

When I tried sending a data with Postman, it returned a value to its localhost but nothing to the uri that I targeted

[image: sending data]

[image: uri target]

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the uri specified is proper.

Please find that :

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64395/api/");
```

and `await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/articles", article);`

gives us: `http://localhost:64395/api/api/articles`